# State observer design

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system, systems-theory

Consider the following LTI system:
$$
  x(k+1)=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0  \\
    \end{bmatrix} x(k) + \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} u(k) \quad {and} \quad y(k) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix} \\
$$
Design a state observer so that the state estimation error
$$ e(k) = x(k) - \hat{x}(k) = 0 \text{ for k } \geq \text{ 2}
$$

How do you determine the L matrix from this? I have done problems where they provide poles placement. But this problem is different where it asks for zero error when  k>=2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the question